# bootstrap datetimepicker disabling other fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp-classic, datetimepicker

I was wondering what the [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) used for storing the date? I want to know how I can use that object/text/whatever it may be to disable other textbox fields that I have on my web page.

I have one page setup for querying against multiple GridViews, so I don't want the user to enter information into multiple fields otherwise more than one GridView will be returned. I have gotten the other textbox fields to become disabled, including the DateTimePicker textbox fields, using the below javascript (jquery):

```
$("#tasknameText").keyup(function (e) {
            if ($(this).val() != '') {
                $("#textDate").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                $("#beginDate").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //DateTimePicker Field
                $("#endDate").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //DateTimePicker Field2
                $("#beginDate2").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //DateTimePicker Field3
                $("#endDate2").attr('disabled', 'disabled'); //DateTimePicker Field4
            } else {
                $("#tasknameText").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#textDate").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#beginDate").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#endDate").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#beginDate2").removeAttr('disabled');
                $("#endDate2").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
```

The above code represents four DateTimePicker fields, or two pairs of Start Date and End Date fields. It works to disable all the other textboxs on the page when I use keyup on a regular textbox. However, keyup only works when the user manually enters a date into the DateTimePicker fields - I need it to work when the user clicks the glyphicon icon and the date is automatically populated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work - instead of using keyup, i just called all the events in the same line and that seemed disabled the other text fields. Would still like to know which one specifically it is changing on...

```
$("#beginDate").bind("blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click" + " dblclick mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter " + "mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error", function (e) {
```